# Viadeo Social Toolbox is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, viadeo

I tryed to use a Viadeo Social Toolbox, exactly the Viadeo Share Button, but it is not working in every browser?!

I found some old viadeo share urls like this: [http://www.viadeo.com/shareit/share/?url=${url}&title=${title}](http://www.viadeo.com/shareit/share/?url=$%7Burl%7D&title=$%7Btitle%7D)

But is not working also.
I searched some jQuery  plugins but they didnot include viadeo sharing options.

Could you please provide me a webservice or API for sharing on viadeo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue have been solved after an update done to the web api of Viadeo Share API